# Remove 'id' field as default sort option

Tags: loopback

I have a model called User which has a hasMany relationship with another model Book. Now, when a request is made on the endpoint: api/users/{{userid}}/books, the sql it uses to fetch books adds order by id in books automatically.

Is there any way to remove this option in model config or via overriding this remote method __get__Books?

I am using loopback3 for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

add `"disableDefaultSort":true` in datasources.json

for example:

```
  "mongodb": {
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 27017,
    "url": "",
    "database": "admin",
    "password": "",
    "name": "mongodb",
    "user": "",
    "connector": "mongodb",
    "disableDefaultSort":true
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have found is to override the find method of Model like below:

```
const builtInFindMethod = Book.find;
    Book.find = function findBooks(filter, ...args) {
const processedFilter = { ...filter, order: 'price ASC' };
      return builtInFindMethod.apply(this, [processedFilter, ...args]);
    };
```